# Python Code who search values in some columns and pickup values from others problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have the next python code:

```
import os
import csv
import requests
import json

# Set the input values to search for

with open('C:/asg/ftpfiles/!searcher/01parseall.json') as json_file:
    dataparse = json.load(json_file)

PartNumber = dataparse['distributornumsku']
vendorPartNumber = dataparse['manufacturervendor']

print (PartNumber)
print (vendorPartNumber)

#input ("Press any key")

search_values = [PartNumber, vendorPartNumber]

# Set the directory path to search for CSV files
directory_path = 'C:/asg/ftpfiles/!!!!!allsearch'

# Set the column letters to search for the input values
search_columns = ['A', 'C']  # set to the column letters to search for the input values

# Set the column letters to pick up for the matching row
pickup_columns = ['A', 'C', 'E', 'U', 'T', 'AC']  # set to the column letters to pick up for the matching row

# Loop through each file in the directory
for filename in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if filename.endswith('.csv'):
        
        # Open the CSV file
        with open(os.path.join(directory_path, filename),  encoding="utf8", newline='') as csvfile:
            
            # Create a CSV reader object
            csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            
            # Read the header row to get the column letters
            headers = next(csvreader)
            num_columns = len(headers)
            
            # Loop through the rows in the CSV file
            for row in csvreader:
                
                # Check if any of the search values are in any of the search columns
                for search_column in search_columns:
                    if row[ord(search_column) - 65] in search_values:
                        
                        # If a search value is found in a search column, print the pickup values
                        pickup_values = [row[ord(pickup_column) - 65] for pickup_column in pickup_columns]
                        print(pickup_values)
                        
                        
                        # Stop searching after finding the first match in any search column
                        break
```

What it does the code is supposed search inside a directory fulled with multiple csv files 2 values from variable “search_values” and search them in all columns “search_columns” if they are found the script will pickup other values from columns in “pickup_columns”. I use the way to search by the column Letter, A,B,C,etc. to avoid use the real header name, I prefer use A,B,C,D,etc. format.

These are the 2 values I input to the code via JSON file:

```
{"distributornumsku": "9B0TP-000K-00781", "manufacturervendor": "956000001"}
```

This is one example of csv file I input in the directory for files search:

https://easyupload.io/u7banh

The error I have is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "C:\asg\ftpfiles!searcher\searcher.py", line 52, in <module>pickup_values = [row[ord(pickup_column) - 65] for pickup_column in pickup_columns]File "C:\asg\ftpfiles!searcher\searcher.py", line 52, in <listcomp>pickup_values = [row[ord(pickup_column) - 65] for pickup_column in pickup_columns]TypeError: ord() expected a character, but string of length 2 found
```

What is needed to modify in the script to make work?

I tried the code above but I can’t make i t work.

Comment: For your code to work the way it is you need the column letters need to be actually 1 letter, but you have one in `pickup_columns` that is 2 letters; `'AC'`

Comment: Oh I see is there a way to fix to accept the AC? The problem is we receive files and they are already formatted like that or others type, also can be “AFD”, etc.

Comment: Then I really don't get the code, because you use `ord(column_letter) - 65` as index. `ord()` returns the integer value of a single letter.

Comment: You could better use `csv.DictReader`. That will make each row a dict, so you can use the actual column names as key.